# Azure Pipelines Stage Condition with Variable

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am running into an issue where I'm trying to execute the following logic on the `stage` `condition`

In plain text, it should work like this:

`(branch is release AND var undefined) OR (branch is release AND var == sys)`

The way I'm trying to do that in my YAML is like this:

```
  # SYS
  - stage: BuildSYS
    condition: or(and(startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release/'), eq('[variables.Env]', '')), and(startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release/'), eq('[variables.Env]', 'SYS')))
    jobs:
      - job: 
        steps:
          - script: echo Hi form SYS!
```

`Env` in this case is a variable that I pass into the pipeline.

[image: Variable]

I am on a `release/*` branch when I trigger, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `'[variables.Env]'` is the issue. Please repleace it to `variables['Env']`.

So your condition should be:

```yaml
condition: or(and(startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release/'), eq(variables['Env'], '')), and(startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release/'), eq(variables['Env'], 'SYS')))
```